# MenuItem Link not working on dropdown menu

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

My Profile link is not working in my dropdown menu. I would like to, when clicked the profile tab to direct to the /user page. Currently nothing happens when clicked except the menu being closed. My component is:

Navbar.js

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.userItem}>
          <Button onClick={handleClick}>
            <span className={classes.userItemText}>Username</span>
          </Button>
          <Menu
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            keepMounted
            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
            onClose={handleClose}>
            <MenuItem componenet={Link} to='/user' onClick={handleClose}>
              Profile
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
          </Menu>
        </div>
  )
}
```

I have other MenuItem Link components on my nav bar working correctly so I can not figure out why this one is not working. Thanks!

SOLVED: After staring at this for 30 minute to an hour, I realized I spelled component wrong. Thanks to people who viewed... will leave up incase someone needs something similar.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: I realized I spelled component wrong.

```
<MenuItem component={Link} to='/user' onClick={handleClose}>
    Profile
</MenuItem>
```